# Not sure if Cox or Gaussian glmnet regression is appropriate

Tags: survival, feature-selection, cox-model, regularization

I am working with data from an outpatient physical rehab clinic and am trying to figure out what variables can predict the *number of hours of service provided* (DV). We have two years of data with a set start and end date. I only have data from clients who entered on or after the start date. I have some clients who enter enter the clinic and exit the clinic within my start and end dates and I have others who enter but are still receiving services at the end date. At times people who are in the clinic for 3 months will have received more hours than people who are in the clinic for 6 months.

I'm planning to use elastic net regression to identify the key variables but I'm stumped regarding the glmnet family I'd be using. Because I'm looking at the total hours of service provided which is not technically a time-to-event analysis (or is it?) do I just treat it as Gaussian or should I be using Cox regression?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you treated the service-hour distribution as Gaussian, you would still need to deal with the censoring problem in some way. Censoring here means clients who were still attending clinic at the end of your study, so you only have a lower limit on how many hours of service they will receive. Survival analysis with a Cox proportional hazards model has the advantage of handling the censoring naturally without any assumption about the underlying shape of the the service-hour distribution among clinics, and can easily incorporate other covariates that you suspect might be associated with service hours.

You could set the start time (0) for each case as the first entry to the clinic, the "event" as "exiting the clinic", and the time to the event as the number of service hours provided before the exit. Those who are still in the clinic at the end of the study would be considered censored, at a time representing the number of service hours before the study ended. Then you would have a simple survival model, just with a less-than-usual measure of time.

Whether that's the best way to proceed is another question. For example, do you care about how many visits there were or the lengths of individual visits, not just the total number of hours? That would require more sophisticated modeling, although it could still be done with survival analysis tools.